# Cable replacement - Headset to PC

Tags: audio, cable, audio-adapters

I am looking for a cable, and I can't find it at all at any store.
The cable has : one pin going to the headset(on the right). The other two are the normal `Mic`(middle) and `Out` for audio(left) of a PC. And a microphone in the bottom of the picutre. 
[image: Cable]
Do you know what this is called ?
Or any suggestion for a workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find such a cable you can replace it with two:

- [mic-in-cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0763HQK92)
- [splitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071NDLCGC)

Those products are just an example.

As a bonus without the splitter you can use this as a headset with your mobile phone.